# making web requests in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Does anyone know how to make a web request to a service using silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

same host as where the silverlight app came from?  that's a normal WCF kind of call:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794260.aspx

If it's on another domain, you've got to allow it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/03/07/enabling-cross-domain-calls-for-silverlight-apps-on-self-hosted-web-services.aspx